# Passing a count to a user command with neovim's Lua API

Tags: neovim, command-line, vimscript-lua

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("TestCommand", function(opts)
    print(opts.count)
end, { count = 1 })

vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-x>", "<cmd> TestCommand <CR>")
```

This will always print `1`, even if I call the keybind with a number prefix. Is there a way to pass the count to the user command using the Lua API?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `count = 1`, i.e., your command can take a count in the "line number position," consider using:

```
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-x>", ":TestCommand <CR>")
```

The default behavior of `:` is to place the count before the command.

Another option is to create an expression map which uses `v:count` inside the command

```
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-x>", function() 
     return "<cmd>echo " .. vim.v.count .. "<cr>" end, {expr = true})
```